# Permission and ownership issue in elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a ruby on rails app deployed to aws using elastic beanstalk. The code has a portion like

```
system("echo intializing git")
`git config --global user.name soumjo`
`git config --global user.email soumjo@gmail.com`
`cd && touch .netrc`
`chmod 600 .netrc`
File.write(".netrc",
    <<-HEREDOC
machine github.com
login soumjo
password 123456
HEREDOC
    )
```

When I downloaded the code after deploy. I can't see file `.netrc`. in the code.

Comment: change permission from command line to 600

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422370/chmod-changing-permissions-of-netrc-operation-not-permitted-ruby

Comment: You mean from aws command line? How to do it. I already tried from local command line. After I deployed to aws. Still the file is not generating

Comment: The Unix convention of a .netrc file is alive and well in aws!

Create a .netrc file in your home directory with this line:

machine AWS username ignored login EC2_ACCESS_KEY password EC2_SECRET_KEY
From now on, aws will use the contents of that file if the standard EC2_ACCESS_KEY and EC2_SECRET_KEY environment variables are missing.

Comment: The code in my question will create .netrc in home directory. Then how I can create another in home directory

Comment: These are the environmental variable set https://i.postimg.cc/nrmmj0Bs/jj.png What variables are missing